# Why doesn't cross sectional area impact yield stress for a given metal?

Tags: material-science

Let's say I have two cylindrical objects of the same metal (so they have the same Young's modulus), but object A has a greater diameter than object B.

If both object A and object B are under a tensile strength test, shouldn't object A have a greater yield stress due to a greater cross sectional area?

I understand that both of these objects have the same Young's modulus so their properties would be similar, but engineering stress is defined as force/initial area so the dimensions of the object should impact its ability to withstand permanent deformation.

But this is not the case as my textbook stated that two objects made from the same material will have the same yield stress, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've edited my question.

Comment: Thank you. That edit makes things much clearer  as to the source of the misunderstanding (actually I guess it was there in the second sentence but didn't call itself to my attention as much stress vs strength).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yield stress is a property of the material, not the geometry. The yield stress is the stress at which it will transition from elastic to plastic deformation. Since as you say, stress = force/area, an object with a larger cross sectional area will require a proportionally larger force reach the yield stress, compared to one with a smaller sectional area.

Stress is Force/Area, so for a given yield stress 's', the maximum force (simplistically, assuming pure axial tension say) would = yield_stress * cross_sectional_area, and clearly a larger sectional area with a fixed yield stress will give a larger load capacity in the elastic region.

Consider two steel rods, of yield stress 355MPa, subject to tension:

Rod 1 has sectional area 1000mm2, therefore force required to cause yielding = 355x1000 = 355,000N = 355kN.

Rod 2 has sectional area of 200mm2, therefore force required to cause yielding = 355x200 = 71,000N = 71kN.

Young's modulus (elastic modulus) is not relevant. Many materials have the same modulus but different yield stress. For example S235 and S355 steel effectively have the same elastic modulus (210GPa), but yield stresses (under defined conditions) of 235MPa and 355MPa respectively.

Comment: And impact loads on steel is a whole different story.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that instead of the two different rods, you have two identical ones. Shouldn't the tensile test require twice the force for the two same rods in paralel  than for just a one? If yes, it is twice the force divided by twice the area, which leads to the same stress.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistook the "yield stress of a material" as "stress of a meterial under load".

For simplicity, the stress of material under load is defined as $"\sigma = \dfrac{P}{A}$. For instance, say we have two $A50$ rods, with $A_1 = 2 in^2$, and $A_2 = 1 in^2$. Now we apply a 50 kips force to the rods, and the results are:

$\sigma_1 = \dfrac{50}{2} = 25  ksi$, and ,

$\sigma_2 = \dfrac{50}{1} = 50  ksi$

Here we say rod 1 has a "stress ($\sigma$)" of 25 ksi, and rod 2 has reached the "yield stress ($\sigma_y$)" of the material - "$50 kai$", which is the "defined" yield stress of $A50$ material (ASTM grade 50 material).

In the graph below, the stress of the rod is represented by a value on the vertical axis while the "yield strength/stress" is the value of the distinct point (yield) on the stress-strain curve.

[image]

Hope this clarifies the confusion.